# clickable and unclickable button android Studio

Tags: android, xml, button, clickable

[image: this is a screenshot of the app]I am currently making a small application and this is what I want to do:
every time I click on the "+" button, I want to increment my counter which I have successfully done. Every time I click the "-" button, I want to decrement my counter which again, I have successfully done. however, when the value of the counter reaches 0, I want my button for "-" to be no longer clickable and be greyed out, how would i be able to do this?

Comment: If you have successfully completed increment and decrement logic then you can disable your button easily.

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is in your onCreate Method

```
Button fewer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fewer);
```

and then you can use **.setClickable(false);**

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
button.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: when i put that into the java code, it says that "cannot resolve symbol button", what should button relate to?

Comment: button should relate to your "-" button

Comment: @carlsaptarshi this is just example. 'button' is an instance of class Button. So in your code you need to replace it with your variable name

Comment: my button id is : android:id = "@id/fewer" so do i call my button fewer.setClickable(false)?

Comment: replace 'button' with variable that is used in your activity. You have some actions made on the buttons so in your code you need to have instance of the button. Use it

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button with `setClickable(false)` (as metnionned by Fixus) or you could also check in the listener if the value is equal to 0, and then if it's the case, just do nothing

Answer (score 0):

fewer.setClickable(false) or 
android:clickable="false" in your xml